# Job scheduling using bull and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to do some scheduling using [bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull). Here is my code

```
const avqueue = new Bull('avque');

avqueue.add({ video: '' }, { repeat: { cron: '*/50 * * * * *' }} );

avqueue.process( function(job, done) {
  console.log('avqueue');
  done();
});
```

But it is getting executed in every milliseconds.Please let me know if I miss any param or someting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a mistake on the cron configuration.

`cron: '*/50 * * * * *'` is an [invalid configuration](https://crontab.guru/#*/50_*_*_*_*_*)

---

The cron configuration only support 5 elements and not 6.

The [correct configuration is](https://crontab.guru/#*/50_*_*_*_*) :

```
cron: '*/50 * * * *'
```

---

In this [bull guide](https://optimalbits.github.io/bull/) you can see the following example :

```
// Repeat every 10 seconds for 100 times.
const myJob = await myqueue.add(
  { foo: 'bar' },
  {
    repeat: {
      every: 10000,
      limit: 100
    }
  }
);

// Repeat payment job once every day at 3:15 (am)
paymentsQueue.add(paymentsData, { repeat: { cron: '15 3 * * *' } });
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction.So if I need to run it in every 2 minutes then is it fine `cron: '*/2 * * * *` . Because it's not working.

Comment: If the bull library match exactly the *crontab* syntax, then it should be `*/2 * * * *`. Use the [following website to test it out](https://crontab.guru/#*/2_*_*_*_*)

Comment: Yes I have tried with that and it's not working as expected.I don't know what's wrong

Comment: OK . I have found [this](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/675#issuecomment-325228468). That was the main problem.